# The "Tipos" model has no "Situacao" relation

Tags: php, doctrine, symfony

Opa, estou tentando fazer uma relação entre duas tabelas porém está me retornando esse erro, acima. Não tenho ideia do que está errado.

essa é a minha estrutura YAML:

```
Tipos_denuncias:
 connection: doctrine
 tableName: tipos_denuncias
 columns:
 situacao:
  type: integer(8)
  readonly: false
  notnull: false
  comment: Situacao
  extra: { label: Situacao, tooltip: Informe a situação da denúncia. } 
 relations:
   Situacao:
   Class: Situacoes
   foreignAlias: Situacao
   local: situacao
   foreign: id
   type: one
   foreignType: many

   Situacoes:
    connection: doctrine
    tableName: situacoes
    columns:
           id:
            type: integer(8)
            primary: true
            readonly: true
            autoincrement: true
           descricao:
            type: varchar(10)
            readonly: false
            notnull: true
            comment: Descrição
            extra: { label: Descrição, tooltip: Descrição da Situação. }
```

e essa é a minha estrutura Symfony:

```
public function configure()
{
  $this->widgetSchema['situacao'] = new sfWidgetFormDoctrineChoice( array('label' => 'Situacao', 'method' => 'getSituacao', 'extra' => array("label" => "Situacao", "tooltip" => "Informe a situação da denúncia."), 'model' => $this->getRelatedModelName('Situacao'), 'order_by' => array("descricao", "asc"), 'add_empty' => ''));
 }
```

Está acusando erro no Alias, porém eu acho que está certo.
Alguém consegue ver algum erro?

Comment: Em que namespace suas entidades estão contidas?

Comment: Cara, eu acho que não tá em nenhum. O sistema já estava criado só dou manutenção, ou, Seja mais claro com sua pergunta.

Comment: Abra a classe `Situacoes` e veja o namespace em que ela está. É a primeira linha de código.

Comment: em Situacoes.class.php: class Situacoes extends BaseSituacoes
{ }

Comment: Então sua classe está no namespace global. O que eu suspeito é que na classe Tipo não há o atributo que referencia a entidade Situacao, ou o atributo está com o nome errado.

Comment: exato, eu não estou conseguindo fazer a referência da chave estrangeira no symfony. No Banco de dados eu fiz a referencia, no arquivo schemas.yml para a configuração das tabelas eu fiz a referencia tambem, mas eu notei que no arquivo schemas.sql dentro de data>sql, não existe a minha de alter table contendo a adição da chave estrangeira na tabela tipos. Estou tentando descobrir o erro ainda.